# Unable to align the image and text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a certificate using HTML and CSS but it's not working. I want to design something like what is shown in the above image but I am facing difficulties in aligning the image and text. Can anyone help me please?

My code:

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

    .l1
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 200px;
      
    }
     .l2
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 200px;
      
    }
    
    .centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div  class="container">
    <img src="l3.jpg"  height="600"  class="l3"/>
    <img src="l1.jpg"  style = "align:left" width="100" height="100" class="l1"/>
    <img src="l2.png" style = "align:right" width="100" height="100" class="l2"/>
    
    
   <div class="centered"  style= "color: lightblue" >This is to certify that the building described herein has been inspected and confirms substantially to the approved drawings & to the requirements of all the applicable codes, laws, rules and regulations that were in place at the time of the issue of this certificate.</div>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some major errors in your code that need to be fixed. You have a malformed `<!doctype>` tag. You have a double nested `<style>` tag with a `<meta>` tag inside of it. If you fix these issues, you may just solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for something like this ( You can, of course, change the order of the images)
[image: website pic]

If yes, then here is the code

```
<!Doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    <meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style>.container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .l1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 200px;
    }

    .l2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 700px;
    }

    .l3 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 500px;
    }

    .centered {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="l3.jpg" height="600" class="l3" alt="img3" />
    <img src="l1.jpg" style="align:left" width="100" height="100" class="l1" alt="img1" />
    <img src="l2.png" style="align:right" width="100" height="100" class="l2" alt="img2" />

    <div class="centered" style="color: lightblue">This is to certify that the building described herein has been inspected and confirms substantially to the approved drawings & to the requirements of all the applicable codes, laws, rules and regulations that were in place at the time of the issue of this certificate.</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here you just needed to change the value of the left attribute of the absolute position or else they will be stacked over each other. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that you have your meta element inside your style tag.
Also, you have  written twice in the beginning.

Quick Tip: If you freshly create a HTML file, you can type '!' and hit Enter. This will generate you a good start. Helps a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, What you have posted to this question cannot be considered as an answer. It would have be better if you had posted it as comment. Because it does not contain any answer for the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.l3 {
  width: 100%
}

.l1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 2;
}

.l2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 8px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div  class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"  height="600"  class="l3"/>
  <div class="centered"  style= "color: lightblue" >This is to certify that the building described herein has been inspected and confirms substantially to the approved drawings & to the requirements of all the applicable codes, laws, rules and regulations that were in place at the time of the issue of this certificate.</div>
</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"  style = width="100" height="100" class="l1"/>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" style =  width="100" height="100" class="l2"/>
```